# Jquery clone element in html

Tags: jquery, dom, clone

Here I am using jQuery ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: URL,
    data: { Mode: "POB1"},
    success: function (data) {
        var Html = $.trim($(data).find("#divpob").html());
        if (Html) {
            $(Html).find(".lblpob").text("UserName" + Username);
            $(".DivRprt").html(Html);
        }
    }
});
```

here value of `lblpob` didn't get change, but if i use `.clone()` like this

```
if (Html) {
    var Html2 = $(Html).clone(true);
    $(Html2).find(".lblpob").text("UserName" + Username);
    Html = Html2;
    $(".DivRprt").html(Html);
}
```

`lblpob` gets changed.

What difference `.clone()` is making here ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's an issue with temporary DOM objects and html as string. I'll break it down line by line:

### What your first code does:

```
    var Html = $.trim($(data).find("#divpob").html());
```

Both the call to `.html()` and to `$.trim()` makes sure your `Html` var holds a **string**, not a live DOM object.

```
    $(Html) ...
```

This turns the `Html` string into a **new** DOM object (that you don't assign into a var),

```
    ... .find(".lblpob").text("UserName" + Username);
```

and change this unnamed DOM object. Not your `Html` string.

```
    $(".DivRprt").html(Html);
```

But here you use the original `Html` string to change the html of `DivRprt`.

### What your other code does:

```
    var Html2 = $(Html).clone(true);
```

After creating a new DOM object and cloning it, you assign it into `Html2`,

```
    $(Html2).find(".lblpob").text("UserName" + Username);
```

and here you manipulate it.

```
    Html = Html2;
    $(".DivRprt").html(Html);
```

So here you insert the manipulated DOM object into `.DivRprt`

### My option:

You don't need the `.clone()`, just keep track of the first DOM object:

```
    if (Html) {
        var Html2 = $(Html)
        Html2.find(".lblpob").text("UserName" + Username);
        $(".DivRprt").html(Html2);
    }
```

### Or:

Just don't convert the trimmed data back to string

```
    var Html = $(data).find("#divpob");
    if (Html.length) {
        Html.find(".lblpob").text("UserName" + Username);
        $(".DivRprt").html(Html);
    }
```

Comment: Fantastic way of providing an answer.  I'm going to attempt to use this type of format in future answers.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case, you're saving the jQuery result into a variable:

```
var Html2 = $(Html).clone(true);
```

It would have worked without the `.clone()` as well, because if you're making modifications to a jQuery collection without saving it into a variable *or* calling `.appendTo()`, those changes would be lost.

**Improvement**

Instead of doing DOM -> HTML serialization followed by HTML -> DOM, you can skip one step and avoid having to keep any variable by doing this:

```
$(data).find("#divpob")
    .find(".lblpob")
        .text("UserName" + Username) // modify
        .end()
    .appendTo('.DivRpt'); // append to container
```

Answer (score 0):

**For jQuery is manipulating DOM, elements must be on DOM.**

instead of:

```
var Html = $.trim($(data).find("#divpob").html());
```

replace:

```
var Html = $(data).find("#divpob");
```

instead of:

```
$(Html).find(".lblpob").text("UserName" + Username);
```

replace:

```
Html.find(".lblpob").text("UserName" + Username);
```

instead of:

```
$(".DivRprt").html(Html);
```

replace:

```
p$(".DivRprt").html(Html.html());
```

Because;

`$(Html).find(".lblpob").text("UserName" + Username);`

In here, `$(Html)` is instant object and you're manipulating instant object.

So your manipulations disappears.